# Javascript Empty String vs (null and undefined)

Tags: javascript

I have a object

```
var data = {1:undefined,2:null,3:10,4:""}
```

I want to replace all the undefined and null values by 0. I am using the following code to do that:

```
for (var index in data) {
    if (!data[index]) {
        data[index] = 0;
    }
}
```

Result I am expecting is :  `{1:0,2:0,3:10:4:""}` 
But Result is :  `{1:0,2:0,3:10:4:0}` because it is considering empty string as null. Is it known behavior ?

I can check it by using 
`(if(data[index] == undefined || data[index] == null))` 
But I wanted to know the behavior of the above solution.

Comment: [yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: undefined was not the question, but empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `typeof data[index] != 'string'`

```js
var data = {1:undefined,2:null,3:10,4:""}

for (var index in data) {
  if (!data[index] && typeof data[index] != 'string') {
    data[index] = 0;
  }
}

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because a string of length 0 is "falsy", which means that it, if evaluated as a boolean, will translate to `false`. Read more on "falsy" [over here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). You can fix your code in the following way:

```
for (var index in data) {
    if (typeof data[index] == "undefined" || data[index] == null) {
        data[index] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michaël for useful link.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ((typeof <your variable> == "undefined") ||
    (       <your variable> == ""         )    ) {
    <your variable> = 0 ;
}
```

By the way, Are you using "1", "2" indices?